# Как мне выровнять 3 блока div ровно о ширине?

Tags: html, css

Имеется такой код* суть вопроса думаю поняли. :)

---

- http://jsfiddle.net/AEDnA/

Comment: А они выровнены ровно по ширине и в вашем примере. Может вы другое имели введу?

Answer (score 1):

Задайте ширину в %, это решит задачу

```
.spf .category {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: За что минусуете человека? Всё правильно сказал. `.spf .category { width: 33.33%; }` надо. http://jsfiddle.net/6eor1y5m/

Comment: @SlyDeath Скорее всего, минус был выставлен системой автоматически, так как сработал фильтр ответа низкого качества.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде это свойство:

```
display:table;
```

Comment: Не, не выходит.
Надо по другому видимо.
Протестируйте на http://jsfiddle.net/AEDnA/
Блоки должны быть идентичны.
Может я просто ошибку где-то допустил?

Answer (score 0):

замени 1-ю строку

```
    <span class="spf">
на

    <div class="spf">

Чтобы окружить встроенные данные, используйте тег <span>, а чтобы окружить блок данных – <div>.
```